# Lebesgue measurable set contains interval

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I'm working through Halmos' "Measure Theory" and encountered some problems while trying to prove a theorem, namely I "proved" that every Lebesgue measurable set of positive measure contains an open interval. But I seem to be unable to spot the error in my "proof". Could someone explain to me where it is?

$$P := \{a, b \in \mathbb{R}, a \leq b \mid [a, b)\}, S := \{A_1, A_2, \ldots \in P, \forall i \neq j: A_i \cap A_j = \emptyset \mid \bigcup_{i=0}^\infty A_i \}, U := \{ A \subset \mathbb{R}; A, \text{open} \mid A \}, \mu : P \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, [a, b) \mapsto b - a$$

Furthermore, let $S(P)$ be the $\sigma$-ring generated by $P$. Now denote by $\overline{\mu}: \overline{S} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ the completion of $\mu$, by $\mu^*$, the induced outer measure, by $\mu_*$ the induced inner measure and let $\mu$ also denote its extensin to $S(P)$.

For all $E \subset \mathbb{R}$, $\mu_*(E) = \sup \{A \in S(P), A \subset E \mid \mu(A)\}$.

$$S(P) \supset  U \implies \mu_*(E) \geq \sup \{A \in U, A \subset E \mid \mu(A)\}$$

On the other hand, it is easy to prove, that $S = S(P)$. This implies, that if $A \in S, A \subset E$, we can find $[a_1, b_1), \ldots \in P$, disjoint, such that $$\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} [a_i, b_i) = A.$$

On the other hand we have $\forall i : (a_i, b_i) \subset [a_i, b_i)$, and all the $(a_i, b_i)$ are therefore disjoint. This means $$\mu(A) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty b_i - a_i = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \mu((a_i, b_i)) = \mu(\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty (a_i, b_i))$$

Therefore, since $\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty (a_i, b_i) \in U$, $$\mu_*(E) = \sup \{A \in U, A \subset E \mid \mu(E) \}$$

If now $E \in \overline{S}, \overline{\mu}(E) > 0$, (since $\mu_*(E) = \overline{\mu}(E)$) there must be an $A \in U$, such that $A \subset E$ and $\mu(A) > 0$. But since an open set ($\neq \emptyset$) contains an open, non-empty interval, it follows that $$\exists(a,b): (a,b) \subset E, b > a$

Thanks for checking it out!
Morris

Comment: $S(P)$, if I have understood how you are defining $P$, is just the Borel sets, since it includes the open intervals $(a,b)=\bigcup_{n=m}^\infty [a+1/n,b)$ ($m$ chosen so that $a+1/n<b$).  I am not clear on how you prove that it is a subset of $S$, the set of countable unions of disjoint half open intervals $[a,b)$ which may be singleton sets with $a=b$.  You say "it is easy to prove," hmm.  The most obvious counterexample to your "theorem" is $\mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}$.  That is a Borel set but would not seem to belong to $S$.

Comment: I'm an idiot! You're absolutely right, of course; The reason for me writing "easy to prove" was that I was completely certain I proved this earlier, that it somehow became "trivial" (along the lines of "proof was easy earlier; could repeat instantly if need arises"). But naturally I tricked myself. What I actually did prove (and this really is easy), is that the RING generated by $P$ is $S$ (actually only using finite disjoint unions), not the $\sigma$-ring... I guess my fault for using "obvoius" and "refusing" to think about it... Thanks! @ForgotALot

Comment: If you write 2 \text{sup} E you'll see $2 \text{sup} E$, but if you write 2\sup E you'll see $2\sup E$, with proper spacing.  Likewise 2\sup(E) yields $2\sup(E)$, this time with more space to the left than to the right of "sup".  In a displayed, as opposed to inline, context, any subscript on "sup" will appear directly below it, thus: $$\sup_{x\in E} f(x)$$ \sup is standard usage in LaTeX and MathJax.  And I changed it. ${}\qquad{}$